# python packaging in exe and bin

Tags: python, compilation

Please tell me how to package [my project](https://send.monks.tools/download/54ddc4e37ccb562b/#uZ09JP3tYw9ZxNH6yMh6dQ) correctly in exe and bin.

I have tried to do it via `nuitka` on Linux and virtual Windows.

On Linux, I use this command:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --output-dir=relize-linux --enable-plugin=tk-inter --enable-plugin=numpy --disable-console --product-name=aigod --linux-icon=aigod.ico --linux-onefile-icon=aigod.ico main.py
```

On the virtual Windows environment, I use this command:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --output-dir=relize-windows --enable-plugin=tk-inter --enable-plugin=numpy --windows-disable-console --windows-icon-from-ico=aigod.ico --windows-product-name=aigod --lto=no main.py
```

Compiling and running the binary, both give me the same result (not opened), a pop-up window, supposedly a startup error.

The main file is just a GUI menu on tkinter, although this menu should have shown.

I also tried `pyinstaller`, but still cannot run the binary correctly.

I can't figure out why this happens.

**upd-----------------------------------**
I managed to compile the project using the command:

```
python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --output-dir=relize-linux --enable-plugin=tk-inter --enable-plugin=numpy --disable-console --product-name=aigod - -linux-icon=aigod.ico --include-package-data=classify --include-package-data=data --include-package-data=models --include-package-data=segment --include-package- data=utils main.py
```

But the catch remains, I have additional scripts that are called via `import script2` at the right time.  As I understand it, their dependencies were not determined and the project did not introduce them, plus they are in the main folder along with the main script.  I tried putting them in a separate folder and trying to account for them with `--include-package-data=otherfiles`, but that didn't work.  Tell me how to take them into account too, they are important because the main script is just a menu, and the rest of the scripts do all the work.  Of course, I will try to look at what it writes in the console during the next package, since in this one I indicated without a console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my problem is that I can not pack the main.py script with all its dependencies in exe (windows) or bin (linux) file. To use the program on different computers. I used different methods of packing, but after compiling the program was not launched.

Comment: I assume you are double-clicking on the executable to run it, could you instead open a terminal and run your application form there ? I used to have the same kind of errors with *freezing*, an exception was happening at startup and thus nothing was visible if you only relied on the window system.

Comment: @Lenormju I managed to compile but there was a zagvostka, please read the main post

Comment: @krolaper I had similar issues with PyInstaller, so I put debug verbosity to maximum, and read through thousands of compilation log lines to understand what it was doing, and understand what I was doing wrong (something silly, that was poorly documented by FBS). Because you don't provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to test, we can't help much.

Comment: @Lenormju I provided more than a minimum - the whole project. In short, I took the project yolov5 and edited under me, adding a graphical menu. Now I have achieved that the graphical menu is run, but there is no communication with other scripts to do the job. If you can tell me which command to bind other scripts when wrapping - I would appreciate it. For now it is a conversation without help.

Comment: @krolaper the whole point of a Minimum Reproducible Example is that it is easy for us to reproduce the problem and search for a solution. You are asking me to download a 2.1Go file and search in it for your problem, which takes time. That's why I insist on **minimal**: if it is easy to reproduce, more people will look at your problem. But it requires you to spend time making it minimal. (and oftentimes, the solution will be found along the way)

Comment: @Lenormju unfortunately can not reduce to a minimum, because of these 2 gigabytes - 80% of python library in the venv folder (I uploaded it there so that people do not download them when trying to test, these are nvidia libraries). Project is big, exe on the finish 320mb

Comment: It is usually not considered a good practice to upload the venv content, because it contains packages installed for your specific environment (OS, OS version, Python implementation, Python version, GPU, ...). Typically, your Nvidia binaries are probably useless on my computer. That's why most people craft a `requirements.txt`/`pyproject.toml` containing these dependencies, that anybody can automatically install in a few seconds.

Comment: @Lenormju Corrected the link in the main topic, added logging in the file.

Comment: @Lenormju Finally at least a compile warning appeared. Nuitka:WARNING: Did not follow import to unused 'detect.py', consider include options.
 Used this command: python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --output-dir=relize-linux --enable-plugin=tk-inter --enable-plugin=numpy --disable-console --product-name=aigod --linux-icon=aigod.ico --include-package-data=classify --include-package-data=data --include-package-data=models --include-package-data=segment --include-package-data=utils --follow-import-to=detect.py,resultimg.py,resultvideo.py main.py